# Generate Class Library proxy for WCF

Tags: wcf, proxy, class-library

I'm trying to write an application which gets the WCF address and generated a DLL from it. 
Then I can pass it to another team (dev team) and they can use the DLL to call WCF methods without knowing anything about WCF Address and config.

Dev team knows about method names/contracts, they just don't want to add reference to WCF services they use and prefer to have a dll and just call the method from DLL.

I have heard about `svcutil` which generates a class and a config file. How can I write an application that executes `svcutil` and compiles the generated files in a dll, all programmatically.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Create, Host(Self Hosting, IIS hosting) and Consume WCF servcie](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/11/create-hostself-hosting-iis-hosting-and.html)

you need to self host service and this self host dll you can give to your other team.,..
check for the selfhosting of the wcf service.,.. also check above article which may help you to achieve your task

Comment: Thanks. The WCF services are on a remote address. Is this going to be a problem?

Comment: @Kamyar: as long as that remote system does expose the WSDL file - no, not a problem at all. You can verify by going to the remote address (URL) and adding `?WSDL` in your URL bar - if that produces a "sea of angle brackets" (spits out a long WSDL/XSD at you), then you should be fine (and `svcutil` will be able to read and interpret that XML flood)

Comment: @marc: Thank you. If you have any information about compiling a .cs file with .config file and generating the DLL, please post it as an answer and I'll be glad to accept it as the best answer.